# Background image is not fit on different screens

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have background image in my application but that is not full screen on different devices on tabs it show white space from top and bottom and on some devices it shows white spaces left and right I have checked this property fit: BoxFit.fill,  fit: BoxFit.cover, and fit: BoxFit.contain, all these 3 properties not working.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:launch_review/launch_review.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sweetalert/sweetalert.dart';
import 'news.dart';
import 'Social.dart';
import 'liveStreaming.dart';
import 'Contactus.dart';

const url = 'link is here';

class won extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
      return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Do you want to exit?"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, false);
                  },
                  child: Text("No")),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                  },
                  child: Text("yes"))
            ],
          ));
    }

    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'imges/bg.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ), onWillPop: _onBackPressed,

    );
  }
}


void Orientatoin() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be full screen wrap your image on a SizedBox.expand widget and not on a Center one.

Comment: Rodrigo you are awesome man. Thanks you save my a whole day. stay blessed dear. Perfectly worked

Comment: It resolved every screen issue but still have issue on splash screen

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```dart
Positioned.fill(
            child: SizedBox.expand(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(AppImages.yourimage),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```